# HTML label for name

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use the label `for` attribute for element *name* instead of *id*? Our application has a bug where two checkboxes have the same id, and clicking the label for one checks the another. It would be a pain to change the id due the ugly and complicated HTML generation logic.

However, both checkboxes have a unique name-attribute, and it would be a quick solution to use the label `for` this name. Is this possible?

Comment: Simple answer is __No__ See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for

Comment: Would recommend to not use a quick solution and remove the duplicated ID's to solve the bug.

Comment: are you try with any javascript?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to use label for attribute for element name instead of id?

No.

HTML defines it as relating to the `id`, only the `id`, and nothing but the `id`.

It couldn’t be designed to reference the `name` because the `name` is not unique. The problem you are trying to work around is caused by having non-unique `id`s. The difference with `name` is that they are *allowed* (and sometimes required) to be non-unique.

Consider a group of radio buttons. Each one needs a unique `<label>`, but they have to share a `name` to make them a group.

Comment: Is there any place where I can find an interesting discussion about why is it like this? I think I would made sense to be able to use name

Comment: `name`s are not unique. It wouldn't make sense to be able to use `name`.

Answer (score 3):

You can warp the target element in the label and you won't need the `for` attribute, like this:

```html
<label><input type="checkbox">Label</label>
```

Clicking the label will activate the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for Id as you are using for name if not using for any other functionality and want to make it quick, check again backend developers use conditions with tags and obviously use same ids with them but You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.

See this example, I am using these checkbox categories in my project.

```
  <div class="form-check-label  wrap col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    {% if listing_details.lake %}
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="lake" id="lake" checked>
                    {% else %}
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="lake" id="lake" unchecked>
                    {% endif %}
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="lake">
                        Lake
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

No, but you can add a class attribute to both those HTML elements with a different class name and take action using the class name also.

Comment: This is equally as complicated as just changing the id. Gotta hate the legacy code

Comment: No, you can't. There is no way to associate a label with an input based on the classes it is a member of.

Comment: You can use,var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

Comment: @vishallakhyani — You can, but that has absolutely nothing to do with what the question is asking.