# Can For attribute be connected with the name attribute in HTML forms?

Tags: html

Learned that the for attribute of a label should be connected with the ID attribute of an input element in HTML.

Instead of that can the for attribute be connected with the name attribute of an HTML input element
?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML label for name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420458/html-label-for-name)

Comment: If there is no specification for that, then no, it's not possible

Comment: what do you mean by 'connected'? Please explain what you want to achieve in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript

**jQuery**

```js
$("[forname]").click(function(){
  $("[name="+this.getAttribute("forname")+"]").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label forname="User">Text</label>
<input name="User">
```

**Vanila JS**

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("[forname]");

for(var x=0; x < labels.length; x++){
  labels[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.querySelector("[name="+this.getAttribute("forname")+"]").focus();
  });
}
```

```html
<label forname="User">Text</label>
<input name="User">
```